# How to hide specific columns of a prime react datatable on mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, datatable, primereact

```
return (
    <DataTable value={data}>
        <Column field="column1" header="Column 1" />
        <Column field="column2" header="Column 2" />
        <Column field="column3" header="Column 3" />
        <Column field="column4" header="Column 4" />
        <Column field="column5" header="Column 5" />
        <Column field="column6" header="Column 6" />
        <Column field="column7" header="Column 7" />
    </DataTable>
);
```

I have created a react datatable using primereact UI library, how can I remove some columns in mobile view.